# Qual a diferença entre Lexical Scope e Dynamic Scope no Javascript?

Tags: javascript

- Qual a diferença entre *Lexical Scope e Dynamic Scope*?
- Quais as vantagens de se utilizar cada um deles?
- Quando eles devem ser utilizados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Lexical Scoping(também chamado de escopo estático).

```js
window.onload = function fun() {
    var x = 5;
    function fun2() {
       console.log(x);
    }
    fun2();
};
```

`fun2` é uma função interna que é definida dentro de `fun()` e está disponível dentro do seu escopo. `fun2` não possui variáveis ​​locais próprias, no entanto, como as funções internas(dentro do seu escopo) têm acesso às variáveis ​​de funções externas, `fun2()` podem acessar a variável declarada  `x` na função pai `fun()`.

## Dynamic Escoping:

Poucas linguagens oferecem escopo dinâmico e Javascript não está incluido nesse grupo. Um exemplo é a primeira implementação do `Lisp`, na Sintaxe C-like:

```
void fun()
{
    printf("%d", x);
}

void dummy1()
{
    int x = 5;

    fun();
}

void dummy2()
{
    int x = 10;

    fun();
}
```

`fun` pode acessar `x`(variável) em `dummy1` ou `dummy2`, ou qualquer `x` em qualquer função que chamar `fun` com `x` declarado nele.

```
dummy1();
Irá imprimir 5

dummy2();
Irá imprimir 10
```

O primeiro é chamado de estático porque pode ser deduzido em tempo de compilação, o segundo é chamado dinâmico porque o escopo externo é dinâmico e depende da chamada de cadeia das funções.

O escopo dinâmico é como passar referências de todas as variáveis ​​para a função chamada.

Um exemplo de por que o compilador não pode deduzir o escopo dinâmico externo de uma função, considere nosso último exemplo, se escrevemos algo como isto:

```
if(condicao)
    dummy1();
else
    dummy2();
```

A cadeia de chamadas depende de uma condição de tempo de execução. Se for verdade, a cadeia de chamada é semelhante a:

```
dummy1 --> fun()
Se a condição for falsa:

dummy2 --> fun()
```

O escopo externo de fun em ambos os casos é o chamador mais o chamador do chamador e assim por diante .

***OBS:*** A linguagem C não permite funções aninhadas nem o escopo dinâmico.

<sub>Fonte:</sub> 
 <sub>- [What is lexical scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)</sub>

<sub>- [Lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)</sub>